# Inserting multiple rows in database codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have some issue about the inserting data. It will insert only the waybillno data but the quantity is always same. Please check my code - I think the model is wrong.

#### Controller

```
public function create_cargo_manifest(){
   $core_model = new Core_m;
   $core_model->save_cargo_details($this->input->post());
   redirect('core/cargo_lookup/');
}
```

#### Model

```
function save_cargo_details(){

$quantity =  $this->input->post('quantity');
$waybilldate =  $this->input->post('waybilldate');

$data = array();
foreach($this->input->post('sys_wbdetails') as $sys_wbdetails) {
$data[] = array(
        'waybillno' => $sys_wbdetails,
        'quantity' => $quantity,
        'waybilldate' => $waybilldate,
       );
 }

   return $this->db->insert_batch('sys_cargodetails', $data); 
}
```

#### View

```
<?php foreach($waybill_header as $waybill_header) { ?>
  <?php echo form_open('core/create_cargo_manifest'); ?>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="sys_wbdetails[]" value="<?php echo $waybill_header->waybillno; ?>"></td>
    <td><?php echo $waybill_header->waybillno; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $waybill_header->waybilldate; ?><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $waybill_header->waybilldate; ?>" name="waybilldate"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5" value="<?php echo $waybill_header->quantity; ?>" name="quantity"></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="save"></td>
  <?php } ?>
<?php form_close(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your inputs for quantity have the same name : `quantity`. So you're only submitting the last value in your form. You need to use an array for those inputs (`quantity[]`), just like for your checkboxes. And you might want to do the same for the `waybilldate` inputs.

```
<td><input type="text" size="5" value="<?php echo $waybill_header->quantity; ?>" name="quantity[]"></td>
```

And then in PHP, something like that :

```
$data = array();
// Count distinct entries in the form
$count = count($this->input->post['sys_wbdetails']);

for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $data[] = array(
        'waybillno' => $this->input->post['sys_wbdetails'][$i],
        'quantity' => $this->input->post['quantity'][$i],
        'waybilldate' => $this->input->post['waybilldate'][$i],
       );
}
```

EDIT : also, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12065299/2067786) if you want a clean way to keep track of which form input goes where.

Comment: i think my question is like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211542/inserting-multiple-rows-in-database-on-codeigniter
only the checkbox was deferent